# Hibernate posts insert statement but doesn't save to database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, gwt

I'm attempting to insert a new record into my mysql database;  the Hibernate insert statement prints in the logs but the database does not insert the new record.  There are no errors posted, but my rpcService call prints my onFailure message.  Also: My app reads from the database just fine, so other parts of my app work well.  Below is the code and config:

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0-->
            <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
            <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds -->
            <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
            <property name="c3p0.max_statements">20</property>
            <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
            <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property> <!-- seconds -->

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <!--  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->
    <mapping class="com.local.shared.School"/>
    <mapping class="com.local.shared.SchoolVideo"/>
    <mapping class="com.local.shared.Category"/>
    <mapping class="com.local.shared.Administrator"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

rpcService call:

```
@Override
public void doUpdateSchoolVideo(SchoolVideo schoolVideo) {
    rpcService.updateSchoolVideo(schoolVideo,
            new AsyncCallback<SchoolVideo>() {

                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    caught.printStackTrace();
                    new Exception().printStackTrace();
                    Window.alert("Couldn't update schoolVideo info!");
                }

                public void onSuccess(SchoolVideo schoolVideo) {
                    System.out.println("SchoolVideo table updated!");
                    loadSubmittedVideos(Utilities.getSchoolPage()
                            .getSchool_name());
                }
            });
}
```

rpcService Implementation:

```
@Override
public SchoolVideo updateSchoolVideo(SchoolVideo schoolVideo) {
    System.out.println("Attempting to save the schoolVideo information"
            + "\n");
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
    HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
    School sessionSchool = (School) httpSession.getAttribute("school");
    System.out.println("\n updateSchoolVideo school in session is " +
                        " = " + sessionSchool.getSchool_name() + "\n");

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        School school = sessionSchool;
        System.out.println("\n cachedSchool = " + school + "\n");
        School querySchool = (School) session.get(School.class,
                new Integer(school.getId()));
        System.out.println(querySchool.getId() + " equals id");
        schoolVideo.setSchool_id(querySchool);
        schoolVideo.setReviewed(1);
        System.out.println(schoolVideo.getVideo_name() + " videoname");
        session.save(schoolVideo);
        System.out.println("\n Video Should have been saved in database after upload \n");
        tx.commit();

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (HibernateException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return schoolVideo;
}
```

And my loggin statement showing Hibernate insert:
Hibernate: insert into SchoolVideo (category, image_name, reviewed, school_id, video_name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

So, my rpcServiceImpl method executes right up to the session.save() method call.  The print statement directly after it doesn't print, so I know that's where everything dies.  Anyone have any idea how I can track this lack of db insert now.

Comment: You need to catch (Exception x), or even catch (Throwable x), and log the stacktrace. There is something being thrown, catch it. (If you need to rethrow after logging, wrap it in a RuntimeException).

Comment: I've caught it, a foreign key constraint, thanks for the help

Comment: Since my answer helped you, can you still see my answer to +1 it?

Comment: I'm sorry your answer is not there anymore, I upped your comment.

Comment: Hi, are you using spring?

Comment: No I'm not using Spring.